# Angular 5 - How to use a custom function within a class

Tags: angular

I created a comment class, so i that i can refactor some code and add custom functions within the classes rather than having them all in my component. For example, a function for toggling Like/Dislike of a comment. However, when i create a simple custom function "hello" it does not work.

In my moment.component.ts i have a service which retrieves a "moment" object from my backend. I then use an ngFor in my app-moment-comment component to display each comment by passing in the current comment object. Here the moment is set to type any;

**moment.component.ts**

```
<app-moment-comment [comment]="comment" class="comment" *ngFor="let comment of moment?.comments></app-moment-comment>
```

**comment.component.ts**

```
export class MomentCommentComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() comment: Comment

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.comment.hello();

    }
```

**comment.model.ts**

```
export class Comment {

    _id: any;
    body: any;
    moment: any;
    author: any;
    likes: any;
    dislikes: any;
    parent: any;
    replies: any;

    constructor() {
        console.log(this);
    }


    hello() {
        console.log("hello")
    }



}
```

When i call the hello() method, i get an error saying:

> ERROR TypeError: this.comment.hello is not a function

Comment: the problem is your are using the field as an input, is you don't pass a object type Comment through the template, this component will receive null in the field comment and your function hello will be undefined

Comment: It means that the object on which you're calling hello() is not an instance of Comment. My guess is that you're getting comments from the backend, and hope that the Http[Client] service will create instances of your class when unmarshalling the JSON. But that won't happen.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah that is what im doing. What is the solution here then?

Comment: You see comment is apart of a posts array im recieving from the backend so i pass posts.comment into this comment component. So because its an array inside of posts it causes problems.

Comment: If you want to stick to this design, then you need to transform every object in the deserialized array into a Comment instance. Using `new`, and copying all the fields.

Comment: @JBNizet It seems you dont want to provide that as a solution because? Is the design im following not good? If so how should i approach this?

Comment: I have. Have you read my previous comment? What don't you undertand? You have an array of objects. You want to create an array of comments. What is the concrete problem? You know about loops, or about Array.map(), right? You know how to call a constructor to create a Comment, right? You know how to read a field from an object, and to set a field in another one, right? Have you tried anything? I could of course provide this simple code, and you could copy and paste without even understanding. But then you wouldn't learn anything.

Comment: @JBNizet woah, wasent expecting an attack, just appeared from your previous comment this design was flawed. I thought you might have had something else in mind. if you dont want to provide a solution thats fine.

Comment: There is no attack at all in what I said. Why do you think that? I'm just asking questions, and hoping you'll read, think and try to find the solution by yourself. You don't answer my questions. What can I do about it?

Comment: I don't see the point in carrying on this conversation,  thank you anyway.

Comment: People would try to help, but looks like someone is just downvoting answers that clearly are approaching the problem. The problem is you omitted how you're passing a Comment object to MomentCommentComponent. Update your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @AndréWerlang Will update it now, yea i notice someone is playing with the votes here.

Comment: You need to emit a change event to notify parent.
read @output & Change to solve it.

Comment: Hello Im from the future, wasnt services a thing back in 2017? I started working with angular 2+ in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

In this demo, you only define the data-type of Comment Class, so `this.comment` value is undefined so can't call hello function. Need to initialize Comment class then you can call hello function.

If you are passing data from parent component then you can implement lifecycle hooks OnChanges method like

```
ngOnChanges(){
   if(this.comment){
     this.comment.hello();
   }
}
```

Comment: How do i initialize the comment class and pass in the json data ?

Comment: You need to modify your Comment class.

Comment: Im not following how this would work, given that im using @Input() comment: Comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Comment class.
First, you can create an interface for mapping the data it will same as Comment class like. then

```
export interface IComment {
    _id: any;
    body: any;
    moment: any;
    author: any;
    likes: any;
    dislikes: any;
    parent: any;
    replies: any;
}

export class Comment {

    _id: any;
    body: any;
    moment: any;
    author: any;
    likes: any;
    dislikes: any;
    parent: any;
    replies: any;

    constructor(commentData: IComment) {
       _id: any = commentData._id;
       body: any = commentData.body;
       moment: any = commentData.moment;
       ........
    }


    hello() {
        console.log("hello", this._id + " " + this.body);
    }
}
```

**comment.component.ts**

```
@Input() comment: IComment; // Using interface for mapping data
commentData: Comment;

    ngOnChanges(){
       if(this.commentData){
         this.commentData = new Comment(this.comment);
         this.commentData.hello();
       }
    }
```

If you want to perform any action on the basis of comment class data then write own methods or getter setter for each property for manipulating data like

```
private _id: string;

  public get id(): string {
    return this.id;
  }
  public set id(value: string) {
    this._id = value;
  }
```